# JdbcRowSetImpl cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Please help me, I am only still a student, I've still much to learn. I've searched everywhere and I still can't find any solution to this error so I've resorted to asking here at Stack Overflow...

My imports:

```
import javax.sql.rowset.JdbcRowSet;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.lang.Throwable.*;
```

This is where it gets the error:

```
public static void info() {
        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
            rows = new JdbcRowSetImpl(); // This is where the error is
            rows.setUrl(DB_URL);
            rows.setUsername(DB_USER);
            rows.setPassword(DB_PASS);

        } catch (/*SQLException | */ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Post the relevant part of your code (with imports) and full exception, including Stack Trace.

Comment: import javax.sql.rowset.JdbcRowSet;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.lang.Throwable.*;

Comment: Do not put code in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here... I added it now..

Comment: Nevermind :), Thanks for trying help anyway, I fixed it on my own. It turns out that I needed to import com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl and configure the build path because it can't access it. Eclipse is weird...

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the following library:

```
import com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl;
```

Add the above line of code to the import section of your class